# Set Blogger archive gadget only with labels

Tags: jquery, html, css, blogs, blogger

I have this blog: http://lligaelconte.blogspot.com.es/

I would like that my Archive gadget on the right side gets only arhived with the labels and not with the date.

I would gladly response any questions about the problem.

Thanks!